# Getting Array Index Out of Bounds Exception for one text file, but not for another similar file in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

So I've written this program that receives a text file, takes the data in that file and puts into a 2D char array to print to the screen in various ways. One of the files I have works perfectly, however, there is a problem when trying to print out the second file "diagonally". First, here is the first and simpler file that works just fine:

```
5 4
FILE
WITH
SOME
MORE
INFO
```

In both files, the first two integers indicate the number of rows and columns that will be created for the 2D char array, respectively. Next, here is a part of the code with this file "testfile.txt" and the results of the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    char[][] charArray = readFile();

    printArray(charArray);
    printVerticalArray(charArray);
    printHorizontalArray(charArray);
    printDiagonalArray(charArray);
}

public static char[][] readFile() throws IOException
{
    File myFile = new File("monalisa.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);

    int rows, columns;
    rows = inputFile.nextInt();
    columns = inputFile.nextInt();

    String[] strArray = inputFile.nextLine().split(" ");

    char[][] array = new char[rows][columns];

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        array[i] = inputFile.nextLine().toCharArray();
    }
    return array;
}
.
.
.
public static void printDiagonalArray(char[][] cArray)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        for(int c = cArray[i].length - 1; c >= 0; c--)
        {
            for(int r = cArray[c].length; r >= 0; r--)
            {
                System.out.print(cArray[r][c]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Original Text: 

FILE
WITH
SOME
MORE
INFO

Transformations: 

INFO
MORE
SOME
WITH
FILE


ELIF
HTIW
EMOS
EROM
OFNI


OEEHE
FRMTL
NOOII
IMSWF
```

So this is exactly how the program is supposed to work, however, whenever I try to put the second file "monalisa.txt" into the program, I get the array out of bounds exception and I cannot figure out why. Here is the original second text file (It's a Google Drive link because it would be too large to display here): https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwujWiqVRKKsajlKV1NIWG1uQVU

And here is the result of program with this text file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwujWiqVRKKsUnZYQTU4YmZDWUE

Line 78 in the code is:

```
for(int r = cArray[c].length; r >= 0; r--)
```

So would anyone happen to know why this is happening? And thank to anyone for reading through all of this!

Comment: It looks like you've got your array indices the wrong way round: `System.out.print(cArray[r][c]);` should be `System.out.print(cArray[c][r]);`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I tried that, but the exact same exception occurs :/

Comment: Also `r = cArray[c].length - 1`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Trying that also gives me the same result with the same exception, even when I try to switch c and r, as stated in your first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line

```
for(int r = cArray[c].length; r >= 0; r--)
```

you are not setting initial value for r correctly. You should not check number of rows in current column, but number of rows in general since will be equal for every column. Change this line to

```
for(int r = cArray.length-1; r >= 0; r--)
```